# Orientdb and teleporter issues

Tags: etl, orientdb

I am having difficulty doing a simple use case with Orientdb and teleporter

**Stack:**

OS: Windows 10 / Java: v8 / Orientdb: 2.2 beta2 / Teleporter: 1.0.0 / 
   Database: MS SQL Express 2014

**Setup:**

1. Installed, MS SQL Express 2014 with instance name SQL2014
2. Created new db Graphdb with two tables, Country w/ PK Country ID and Province w/ PK Province ID and FK Country ID
3. Installed, and start Orient db 2.2 beta 2
4. Created new oteleporter_graphdb.bat

   oteleporter.bat -jdriver sqlserver -jurl jdbc:sqlserver://:54963;instance:SQL2014;databaseName:graphdb -juser sa -jpasswd  -ourl plocal:$ORIENTDB_HOME/databases/graphdb -s naive -nr java -v 2

**Test Case:**

1. Run oteleporter_graph.bat as-is

This test case read the db and created warnings for table’s part of sql metadata but Country & Province were not part of it.

2. Modify oteleporter_graph.bat to include both Country and Province table

   oteleporter.bat -jdriver sqlserver -jurl jdbc:sqlserver://:54963;instance:SQL2014;databaseName:graphdb -juser sa -jpasswd  -ourl plocal:$ORIENTDB_HOME/databases/graphdb -s naive -nr java -v 2 –include Country,Province

This test aborted!

3. Modify oteleporter_graph.bat to include only Country table.

   oteleporter.bat -jdriver sqlserver -jurl jdbc:sqlserver://:54963;instance:SQL2014;databaseName:graphdb -juser sa -jpasswd  -ourl plocal:$ORIENTDB_HOME/databases/graphdb -s naive -nr java -v 2 –include Country

This test case ran without any error but didn’t read any table from the database nor output anything out.

**Questions:**

1. Am I missing any configuration steps?
2. Test case #2, how to define multiple tables?
   Other questions:
3. Possible to add filter to the tables?
4. Instead of tables, views can be included? how would teleporter will identify the PKs / FKs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions in order.

1. To install and run Teleporter you have to:

   - extract `orientdb-teleporter-1.0.0.jar` in your `ORIENTDB_HOME/plugins` path.
   - extract the `oteleporter.bat` and `oteleporter.sh` scripts in your `ORIENTDB_HOME/bin` path and launch them from that location with the expected arguments.
2. You can define filters on multiple tables simply by using the syntax you used:
   `-include <tableName1>,<tableName2>,...,<tableNameX>`
   but if you are running Teleporter on Windows probably you need to add quotes to the last argument, so try with:
   `–include "Country,Province"`
3. Filters are possible with a "table-granularity", so you can filter-in or filter-out entire tables but not elements contained in them (e.g. columns).
   In the next versions probably will be possible manage the schema filtering with a finer granularity.
4. Teleporter includes only materialized views (persistent in your database) in the migration and in this first version identifies PKs and FKs starting from the metadata present in the schema of your database. 
   Thus if you don't define a FK between two tables you won't have edges between the correspondent vertices. In the next version of Teleporter will be possible the relationships defining through an input JSON.

If you have any doubt you can refer to official page, documentation and blog posts here:

http://orientdb.com/orientdb-labs/teleporter/
(Official Teleporter Page)

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-labs/blob/master/Teleporter-Index.md
(Official Documentaion)

http://orientdb.com/orientdb-teleporter-making-migrations-easier/
(Blog Post: OrientDB Teleporter - Making Migrations Easier (Part 1) )

http://orientdb.com/orientdb-teleporter-making-migrations-easier-part-2/
(Blog Post: OrientDB Teleporter - Making Migrations Easier (Part 2) )

Comment: Thanks GeberEI. Very helpful!. Can I ask, one more question here (or I can create a new question). On this page, teleporter tries to check and download the files jdbc files which are not found. https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-labs/blob/master/Teleporter-Installation-and-Configuration.md

Comment: Issue is at work, we are working in VM and can't access internet via VM :-( I would like to download files and save it manually. For Oracle, I saved "ojdbc7.jar" to /lib folder and for sqlserver is "sqljdbc4-2.0.jar" saved to /lib folder. But upon restarting the teleporter process it seems like looking for more files and try to connect to orientdb.com - java error "ERROR: java.net.UnknownHostException - orientdb.com" - hope this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying your case with these steps:

1. Copying `orientdb-teleporter-1.0.0.jar` into you `/plugins` folder;
2. Copying `oteleporter.bat` into you `/bin` folder;
3. Creating a new `graphdb` in MySQL with this structure:

   ```
   mysql> select * from province;
   +------------+--------------+-----------+
   | provinceId | provinceName | countryId |
   +------------+--------------+-----------+
   |          1 | Milano       |         1 |
   |          2 | Parigi       |         2 |
   +------------+--------------+-----------+

   mysql> select * from country;

   +-----------+-------------+
   | countryId | countryName |
   +-----------+-------------+
   |         1 | Italia      |
   |         2 | Francia     |
   +-----------+-------------+
   ```
4. From the terminal, go to your `/bin` folder and run this command:

   ```
   oteleporter.bat -jdriver mysql -jurl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/graphdb
   -juser root -jpasswd MyPassword -ourl plocal:C:/path/to/graphdb -s naive -nr java -v 2
   ```
5. Run the `server.bat`;
6. Go to Orient Studio:

[image]

Now you can see the tables correctly created in OrientDB.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks LucaS - 1/  I will try with mysql maybe MS SQL Server Express has some issues; 2/ Do I need to start server.bat after oteleporter.bat? If that is the case, before we sync do we need to turn OFF the server. Can you please try #5 before #4

Comment: Hi @RLx, I have to check, I'll give you a feedback ASAP.

Comment: Hi @RLx, I checked and I noticed that you can have a running server when you launch the `oteleporter.bat`. Hope to have been helpful.

Comment: Great!! I will try this.. plus will add more test cases; hopefully, it will help other users too.

Comment: Perfect. Let me know if everything has gone well.